# I'd like my code to flow with my terminal a little better

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

So I have a fully functional py script running on Ubuntu 12.04, everything works great. Except I don't like my input methods, it's getting annoying as you'll see below. Before I type out the code, I should say that the code takes two images in a .img format and then does computations on them. Here's what I have:

```
import os

first = raw_input("Full path to first .img file: ")
second = raw_input("Full path to second .img file: ")

print " "


if os.path.exists(first) == True:
    if first.endswith('.img') == False:
        print 'You did not give a .img file, try running again'
        os.sys.exit()
elif os.path.exists(second) == True:
    if second.endswith('.img') == False:
        print 'You did not give a .img file, try running again'
        os.sys.exit()
else:
    print "Your path does not exist, probably a typo. Try again"
    os.sys.exit()
```

Here's what I want; I want to be able to feed python this input straight from the Terminal. In other words, I want to be able to input in the terminal something like

```
python myscript.py with the two images as input
```

This way I could make use of the terminal's tab-key shortcut when specifying paths and stuff. Any ideas/suggestions?

EDIT: Ok so I looked into the parsing, and I think I got down how to use it. Here's my code:

```
import argparse

import nipy

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()



parser.add_argument("-im", "--image_input", help = "Feed the program an image", type =     nipy.core.image.image.Image, nargs = 2)
```

however now I want to be able to use these files in the script by saying something like first = parser[0] second = parse[1] and do stuff on first and second. Is this achievable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read/process command line arguments?](/q/1009860/90527)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing that the parsing code already exists, all you need to do is accept command-line arguments with Python's [sys module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html):

```
import sys

first  = sys.argv[1]
second = sys.argv[2]
```

Or, more generally:

```
import os
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':

    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print('USAGE: python %s [image-paths]' % sys.argv[0])
        sys.exit(1)

    image_paths = sys.argv[1:]

    for image_path in image_paths:
        if not os.path.exists(image_path):
            print('Your path does not exist, probably a typo. Try again.')
            sys.exit(1)
        if image_path.endswith('.img'):
            print('You did not give a .img file, try running again.')
            sys.exit(1)
```

### NOTES

The first part of the answer gives you what you need to accept command-line arguments. The second part introduces a few useful concepts for dealing with them:

1. When running a python file as a script, the global variable `__name__` is set to `'__main__'`. If you use the `if __name__ == '__main__'` clause, you can either run the python file as a script (in which case the clause executes) or import it as a module (in which case it does not). You can read more about it [here](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/tutor-what-is-if-name-main-for.htm).
2. It is customary to print a usage message and exit if the script invocation was wrong.
   The variable `sys.argv` is set to a list of the command-line arguments, and its first item is always the script path, so `len(sys.argv) < 2` means no arguments were passed. If you want exactly two arguments, you can use `len(sys.argv) != 3` instead.
3. `sys.argv[1:]` contains the actual command-line arguments. If you want exactly two arguments, you can reference them via `sys.argv[1]` and `sys.argv[2]` instead.
4. Please don't use `if os.path.exists(...)==True` and `if string.endswith(...)==True` syntax. It is much clearer and much more Pythonic to write `if os.path.exists` and `if string.endswith(...)` instead.
5. Using `exit()` without an argument defaults to `exit(0)`, which means the program terminated successfully. If you are exiting with an error message, you should use `exit(1)` (or some other non-zero value...) instead.

Comment: Oh wow, I'm sorry I completely bypassed your answer, and it actually answers it best. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 7):

You want to parse the command line arguments instead of reading input after the program starts.

Use the [`argparse` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html) for that, or parse [`sys.argv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv) yourself.

Comment: How do you answer it so fast? Jeez.

Comment: Haha yeah that was a pretty fast reply I'm impressed! But OK this seems promising, I'll keep reading into the documentation, thanks

Comment: @enginefree: I think he made a python module to check for updates, probably made a better templating language using Python to write better answers. Or maybe its two guys sharing one account, the mysteries of Mr. Pieters will forever remain a mystery! :P

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is take in command line parameters, and the best way to do that is using a nifty module called argparse. I have listed below a good resource on how to install and use it.

[Here](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/modules-in-python/argparse-tutorial/) is a great resource for argparse. It is a module used to take command line arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use sys.argv:

```
import sys

first = sys.argv[1]
second = sys.argv[2]
```

Don't forget to check `len(sys.argv)` before.